# ERROR cuando hago npm start

Tags: angular, npm

resulta que hago todo como dicen en todos los blog para iniciar angular y me da este error.

> fernando@fernando-PCM10:~/Documentos/Proyecto sorteador/tienda de otro/quickstart$ npm start
>   
>  
>   > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 prestart /home/fernando/Documentos/Proyecto sorteador/tienda de otro/quickstart
>   **> npm run build**
>   
>  
>   > angular-quickstart@1.0.0 build /home/fernando/Documentos/Proyecto sorteador/tienda de otro/quickstart
>   **> tsc -p src/**
>   
>   sh: 1: tsc: not found 
>   npm ERR! weird error 127 
>   npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" 
>   npm WARN For further explanations, please read /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian
>   npm ERR! not ok code 0 
>   npm ERR! weird error 1 
>   npm WARN This failure might be due to the use of legacy binary "node" 
>   npm WARN For further explanations, please read /usr/share/doc/nodejs/README.Debian   
>   
>   npm ERR! not ok code 0

Tengo Xubuntu 14.04
Instalo node correctamente, clono el repositorio quickstart de angular4 y cuando le tiro el npm install me da un par de errores. y bueno cuando le doy nom start me da eso que pegue mas arriba.

Busque por tda la web pero desconosco porque me lo hara.
Gracias. Saludos.

Ahi el debug que me tira.

npm-debug.log:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ '/usr/bin/nodejs', '/usr/bin/npm', 'i', '-g', 'npm' ]
2 info using npm@1.3.10
3 info using node@v0.10.25
4 verbose cache add [ 'npm', null ]
5 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="npm" args=["npm",null]
6 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
6 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
6 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
6 verbose parsed url   host: null,
6 verbose parsed url   port: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
6 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
6 verbose parsed url   search: null,
6 verbose parsed url   query: null,
6 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'npm',
6 verbose parsed url   path: 'npm',
6 verbose parsed url   href: 'npm' }
7 silly lockFile 660051d1-npm npm
8 verbose lock npm /home/fernando/.npm/660051d1-npm.lock
9 silly lockFile 660051d1-npm npm
10 silly lockFile 660051d1-npm npm
11 verbose addNamed [ 'npm', '' ]
12 verbose addNamed [ null, '*' ]
13 silly lockFile 2f990b75-npm npm@
14 verbose lock npm@ /home/fernando/.npm/2f990b75-npm.lock
15 silly addNameRange { name: 'npm', range: '*', hasData: false }
16 verbose url raw npm
17 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './npm' ]
18 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
19 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 18:03:54
20 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
21 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
22 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 18:04:05
23 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
24 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
25 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 18:05:06
26 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/npm
27 silly lockFile 2f990b75-npm npm@
28 silly lockFile 2f990b75-npm npm@
29 error Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
29 error     at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1370:32)
29 error     at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
29 error     at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:982:10)
29 error     at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:469:13)
29 error     at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
29 error     at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
29 error     at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:223:10)
29 error     at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:213:5)
29 error     at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
29 error     at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
30 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
30 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
30 error or email it to:
30 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
31 error System Linux 3.13.0-143-generic
32 error command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "-g" "npm"
33 error cwd /home/fernando/Documentos/ProyectoSorteador/tiendadeotro/quickstart
34 error node -v v0.10.25
35 error npm -v 1.3.10
36 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: ¿Probaste utilizando un path sin espacios? El error en si habla sobre la posibilidad de que estés usando una versión vieja de node

Comment: fernando@fernando-PCM10:~/Documentos/ProyectoSorteador/tiendadeotro/quickstart$ node -vv8.9.4
fernando@fernando-PCM10:~/Documentos/ProyectoSorteador/tiendadeotro/quickstart$ npm -v
1.3.10

Comment: ahi le saque los espacios y esas son mis versiones de node y de npm

Comment: ahi edite el post y le agrege el debug.

Comment: seguramente tengas que instalar `tsc` y `typescript` globalmente para que los encuentre en el path -> https://github.com/angular/quickstart/issues/215#issuecomment-290549937

Answer (score 0):

Verifica que tengas instalado nodeJs con el comando `node -v`, de igual forma ejecuta `npm -v` para saber si cuentas con el paquete `npm`.

Si tu proyecto de angular esta en un repositorio, verifica que tenga el archivo `package.json`, otro archivo que debe tener es `.angular_cli.json`.

Corrobora que tengas instalado `angular-cli`.